# Properties of a PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $f(X)=p(1-p)^{X-1}$ with $p\in[0;1]$ and $X$ a discrete random variable which can take on any integer value between $1$ and $+ \infty$.

I want to show that $f$ is a PDF, i.e. it satisfies the properties of a PDF.

- $0<f(X)<1$ was easy to show
- $\sum f(X_{i})=1$ was not, I do not know how to compute this summation to reach exactly $1$.

Any tips?

Comment: f is a function,  so I believe the $X$ variable has nothing to do with all this. You probably need to show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx =1$. What is the exact question you need to answer ?

Comment: @WNG2, I need to show that $f(X)$ satisfies the properties of a probability density function.

Comment: $f(X)$ is a random variable, not a function. So it can not match the properties of a probability density function.  now, maybe you need to show that $f$ does satisfy these properties. Your question makes sense (to me) only if $f$ is the subject and not $f(X)$

Comment: @WNG, I'm not sure what you mean exactly, I thought $f$ and $f(X)$ are equivalent. But the question does state $f(X)$ if that helps.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i)$ is a [geometrical series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). Use: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ar^{n-1} =  \frac{a}{1-r}$.

Comment: @Winther, the question says: "X can take integer values from $1$ to $+\infty$.". Can someone confirm what that means? I thought it meant we have a finite number of $X_{i}$, say $n$, and their values $\in [1;+\infty]$, if however it means that there is an infinite number of $X_{i}$, then I can use what you say.

Comment: @Sadem: To be more precise, one should have written something like $f(x) \equiv P(X = x)$ or something like that.  Strictly speaking, if $f(\cdot)$ is a function, and $X$ is a random variable, then $f(X)$ is itself a random variable.  But I think it's clear enough what was intended. $\Box$ What was wrong with Sahil Kumar's answer?

Comment: @Sadem: It does not mean that there's a collection of random variables $X_i$ for some values of $i$; it means that there is a single random variable $X$ that takes on values from $1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: @BrianTung, I explain what was wrong with Sahil Kumar's answer when replying to Winther. The formulation of the question seems to be imprecise.

Comment: @BrianTung, exactly. That would mean that the summation is finite.

Comment: @Sadem: How so?  You're summing the probabilities, not the random variables.  There are an infinite number of possibilities, so the sum is infinite, not finite.  (It sums to a finite value—$1$, specifically—but the number of terms is infinite.)